# Why are blank and null distinct options for a django model?

Tags: django, django-models

When defining fields in a django model, there are two ways to say that the field is allowed to be empty.  `null` means it can be empty in the database, and `blank` says the field can be empty in a form.  Why are these distinct?  Every time I set one but not the other something goes wrong.  Allowing them to be different seems to be to just inviting problems of the form allowing you to create objects the database won't accept.

In other words, when would you ever use `null=True,blank=False` or `null=False,blank=True` in a django model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`null=False, blank=True` is common for `CharField`s, where a blank answer is stored in the db as a blank string rather than a null. The other way around doesn't make much sense to use.

For non-string fields, a non-answer is stored as a `null`, and so you need both.

Comment: Why would one ever want this behavior though? What is the benefit of storing a bunch of blank strings in the DB instead of just no value at all?

Answer (score 72):

They have two entirely different meanings:

**blank**: determines whether the field should be validated as required or not in forms. `False` means the form will generate an error if not provided, while `True` means empty values are allowed.

**null**: determines whether the field should be set as `NULL` or `NOT NULL` at the DB level. This has nothing to do with form validation.

Some examples:

`blank=True, null=False` would raise an `IntegrityError` anytime the field was left blank, if it's not a CharField or TextField. Those two fields send `''` (empty string) rather than `NULL` to the DB when empty.

`blank=False, null=True` would always require the field to be filled out in all forms (forms will raise `ValidationError` on the field), even though the column is allowed to be `NULL`. However, this only applies to forms. You could manually set the attribute to `None` and save it outside of a form (in a shell, for example).

Comment: +1 with the key difference being `null` affects DB while `blank` affects form validation. Note that a field set with `blank=False` will allow you to save a model with no value for that field. It only throws a validation exception if you try to do so within a ModelForm.

Comment: And I see that Chris said that in his last paragraph. D'oh!

Comment: blank=False,null=True still makes no sense to me. If you change it outside the form, then the record becomes a landmine that will blow up if you ever try to edit it in the form.  I see the logic behind blank=True,null=False, but the other way round seems unlikely to ever be useful and certainly comes with gotchas.

Comment: I think you got those mixed up. `blank=False,null=True` is not dangerous at all. It's just mildly illogical because it forces a value for a nullable field. However, there's use cases where that might be necessary and, remember it only requires when use with a form. `blank=True,null=False`, however, *could* lead to an IntegrityError, but with CHAR and TEXT fieldtypes, Django always stores an empty string, rather than `NULL` so it is quite common with those field types.

Comment: The problem with blank=False,null=True is that you can create objects programmatically that can't be edited with standard forms.  They will display, but you can't save them without changing that field.  This makes no sense - what possible use case is there for this?  Why would you want a form that forces you to modify a valid object?

Comment: One I can think of is in combining that with `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`. This would NULL out the field if the relationship was deleted instead of cascading, but then force anyone editing it afterwards to assign a new relationship.

Comment: @ChrisPratt please correct your second paragraph,`blank=True` means the form **Will NOT** generate an error if the field is left blank.

Comment: @Leopd: sorry to bump a 10 year old comment, but one use case for `blank=False, null=True` is when you add a *new* "mandatory" field to an *existing* model, and a meaningful default value cannot be determined for *existing* objects. In this case,  using the `default` attribute, or creating a data migration, is not an option. Thus, `blank=False` ensures that the field will be set (on forms) for *new* or *newly-modified* objects, and `null=True` makes sure the *existing* objects remain valid.