# Models CharField Blank and Null

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model :

```py
class Scenario(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to ='scenarios-pictures/%Y/%m/%d', default="", blank=False, null=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If I try to create a scenario with empty values, it doesn't raise any exception.

```py
>>> from ihm_maquette.models import Scenario
>>> scenario = Scenario.objects.create(title='', subtitle='', description='', image_url='', slug='')
>>> scenario
<Scenario: >
>>>
```

I don't get why, because I've read in the doc that blank and null are False by default.
[I've also read this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159310/why-are-blank-and-null-distinct-options-for-a-django-model).

Do you have any idea why the object is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null=False` does not mean a `CharField` cannot have an empty string as a value. Also the model's `create` and `save`, etc. methods do not *validate* the model while creating it. The `blank` attribute is used when the model is validated, usually the form will call the various methods on the model available for validating the instance when you call `form.is_valid()`. You can validate an instance by simply calling the `full_clean` method (Reference [Validating objects [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)):

```
from ihm_maquette.models import Scenario


# Don't call create instantiate it first
scenario = Scenario(title='', subtitle='', description='', image_url='', slug='')
scenario.full_clean() # will raise exception here
scenario.save()
```

Comment: Complete answer, just read the reference as well. Thanks !